# Calculating time complexity by just seeing the algorithm code

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, time-complexity

I have currently learned the code of all sorting algorithms used and understood their functioning. However as a part of these, one should also be capable to find the time and space complexity. I have seen people just looking at the loops and deriving the complexity. Can someone guide me towards the best practice for achieving this. The given example code is for "Shell sort". What should be the strategy used to understand and calculate from code itself. Please help! Something like step count method. Need to understand how we can do asymptotic analysis from code itself. Please help.

```
int i,n=a.length,diff=n/2,interchange,temp;
while(diff>0) { 
    interchange=0;
    for(i=0;i<n-diff;i++) {
        if(a[i]>a[i+diff]) { 
            temp=a[i];
            a[i]=a[i+diff];
            a[i+diff]=temp;
            interchange=1;
        }
    }
    if(interchange==0) {
        diff=diff/2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you annotate your code with "never execute"?

Comment: @CommuSoft actually that's the best case i have listed my bad for that.

Comment: So you want to make a *best-case* analysis (instead of *worst-case*)? What is the relevance? Many algorithms are best-case *O(n)* or even less. In general it is not a good metric to evaluate an algorithm.

Comment: My bad on that. Can you help me out with the query how to do asymptotic analysis on them to reach all the possible cases. I just want to understand this process of calculation whether it is best case or worst case and how to reach to that point. Main issue is with getting to the calculative part of time complexity. @CommuSoft

Comment: @CommuSoft can you also help me devise/understand so i can go through all the cases for all of the algorithms so going forward i can learn them better and find it useful to crack other algo's?

Comment: Your algorithm shows some small constant factor inefficiency: why only divide `diff` by `2` if `interchange == 0`?

Comment: as with many aspects in programming: there is no silver-bullet to analyze the time complexity of an algorithm. Especially some recursive ones tend to be very tricky.

Comment: @CommuSoft if [interchange==0] what i would do is divide the earlier diff by 2 and then again perform check with that diff. As i lower down the difference, more i move towards bubble sort and able to compare all elements. Please correct me if i have understand you wrong (which i think i have)

Comment: but you can safely divide `diff` by `2` even if interchange is `0`, simply because you resolved the problem by swapping a second iteration with `diff` set to its original value is unnecessary.

Comment: Furthermore your sorting algorithm doesn't work properly. It should perform the operations the opposite way: increasing `diff`

Comment: Will try with that as well and update the results. Thanks again for your help. This is a great community. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90026/discussion-between-icantcode-and-commusoft).

Comment: @commusoft still need help in understanding worst case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the *absolute lower bound* on worst-case of a *comparison-sorting algorithm* is *O(n log n)*, evidently one can't do any better. The same complexity holds here.

**Worst-case time complexity**:

**1. Inner loop**

Let's first start analyzing the inner loop:

```
for(i=0;i<n-diff;i++) {
    if(a[i]>a[i+diff]) {
        temp=a[i];
        a[i]=a[i+diff];
        a[i+diff]=temp;
        interchange=1;
    }
}
```

Since we don't know much (anything) about the structure of `a` on this level, it is definitely possible that the condition holds, and thus a swap occurs. A *conservative* analysis thus says that it is possible that `interchange` can be `0` or `1` at the end of the loop. We know however that if we will execute the loop a second time, with the same `diff` value.

As you comment yourself, the loop will be executed *O(n-diff)* times. Since all instructions inside the loop take constant time. The time complexity of the loop itself is *O(n-diff)* as well.

Now the question is how many times can `interchange` be `1` before it turns to `0`. The maximum bound is that an item that was placed at the absolute right is the minimal element, and thus will keep "swapping" until it reaches the start of the list. So the inner loop itself is repeated at most: O(n/diff) times. As a result the computational effort of the loop is worst-case:

```
O(n^2/diff-n)=O(n^2/diff-n)
```

---

**2. Outer loop with different `diff`**

The outer loop relies on the value of `diff`. Starts with a value of `n/2`, given `interchange` equals `1` at the end of the loop, something we cannot prove will not be the case, a new iteration will be performed with `diff` being set to `diff/2`. This is repeated until `diff < 1`. This means `diff` will take all powers of `2` up till `n/2`:

```
1 2 4 8 ... n/2
```

Now we can make an analysis by summing:

```
log2 n
------
 \
 /      O(n^2/2^i-n) = O(n^2)
------
i = 0
```

where `i` represents *log<sub>2</sub>(diff) of a given iteration. If we work this out, we get ***O(n<sup>2</sup>)*** worst case time complexity.

> **Note** (On the lower bound of worst-case comparison sort): One can proof no comparison sort algorithm exists with a worst-case time complexity of *O(n log n)*.
>
> This is because for a list with *n* items, there are *n!* possible orderings. For each ordering, there is a different way one needs to reorganize the list.
>
> Since using a comparison can split the set of possible orderings into two equals parts at the best, it will require at least *log<sub>2</sub>(n!)* comparisons to find out which ordering we are talking about. The complexity of *log<sub>2</sub>(n)* can be calculated using the *Stirling approximation*:
>
> ```
>  n
>  /\
>  |
>  |   log(x) dx = n log n - n = O(n log n)
> \/
>  1
> ```

**Best-case** time complexity: in the best case, the list is evidently ordered. In that case the inner loop will never perform the `if-then` part. As a consequence, the `interchange` will not be set to `1` and therefore after executing the `for` loop one time. The outer loop will still be repeated *O(log n)* times, thus the time complexity is ***O(n log n)***.

Comment: Thanks. How do we now get towards best case and average case following the same pattern?

Comment: still need help in understanding the worst case. :(

Answer (score 0):

Look at the loops and try to figure out how many times they execute. Start from the innermost ones.

In the given example (not the easiest one to begin with), the for loop (innermost) is excuted for `i` in range `[0,n-diff]`, i.e. it is executed exactly `n-diff` times.

What is done inside that loop doesn't really matter as long as it takes "constant time", i.e. there is a finite number of atomic operations.

Now the outer loop is executed as long as `diff>0`. This behavior is complex because an iteration can decrease `diff` or not (it is decreased when no inverted pair was found).

Now you can say that `diff` will be decreased `log(n)` times (because it is halved until 0), and between every decrease the inner loop is run "a certain number of times".

An exercised eye will also recognize interleaved passes of bubblesort and conclude that this number of times will not exceed the number of elements involved, i.e. `n-diff`, but that's about all that can be said "at a glance".

Complete analysis of the algorithm is an horrible mess, as the array gets progressively better and better sorted, which will influence the number of inner loops.

Comment: how would you differentiate between best and worst case then?

Comment: My point here is that this code cannot be analyzed in a blink of an eye, and I didn't/won't attempt to do it. You should start with `StraightInsertion`, `StraightSelection`, `Bubble` ..., more straightforward stuff.